# Imported function not working

Tags: python, function

I am pretty new to Python and am trying to import a function I have made in a separate file. When I run the code I get **"TypeError: signal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'handler'"**. I think it means the signal function is not being passed a single argument but I am pretty sure that is what the for loop does. Where am I going wrong? Also, the files are in the same folder, which is a part of the working directory. The code that calls the function is:

```
import numpy as np

t=np.linspace(-5,5,200)

import signal

y=[]
for i in t:
    y.append(signal.signal(i))
```

The function code is saved in a file called signal.py. The code is:

```
def signal(t):
    import numpy as np
    y=np.cos(t)*np.exp(-abs(t))
    return y
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not a specific description of a problem.

Comment: True, I have updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: `signal` is a module in the standard library; you are importing that, not your `signal.py`.

Comment: You are importing this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to import a `signal` from the standard library instead of your own file. Try to import it like this:

```
from .signal import signal
```

PS: Since you are new to Python, you should also make sure you have a an `__init__.py` file in the directory, like so:

```
/Parent
    __init__.py
    main.py
    signal.py
```

Comment: My pleasure. No question is silly, it may still help someone.

Comment: @TomWeisner It was a very real problem, which led to the change in Python documented in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by chepner, you have a module name conflict with pythons inbuilt module `signal`

If the name is not important, then you could change the name.

If the name is important then you could create a package and place the file in that, Then import it.

For example, following will be your directory tree

```
signal_module/
├── __init__.py
└── signal.py
original_file.py
```

Then import the `signal_module` as follows

```
from signal_module import signal
```

**The `__init__.py` file is import.**

It can be empty, but it needs to be created for python to tree the directory as package.

As you said you are new to python, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) to know more about the importance of `__init__.py`